# datetime select with -15 minute interval showing wrong result

Tags: mysql, datetime, intervals

For a room reservation page I'm making a query for entries among 3 tables. Datetime values are in one table, another table keeps the info if the room key has been checked out. And another table keeps the reservation information. If current time has past start of reservation time at least 15 minutes and the key has not been checked out, the entry should get deleted. Problem is, it deletes also future reservations, where the start time of the reservation has not past yet. My query looks like this.

```
SELECT dt.field_reservation_datetime_value
     , dt.entity_id
     , co.field_reservation_checked_out_value
     , co.entity_id
     , res.reservation_id 
  FROM field_data_field_reservation_datetime dt 
  JOIN field_data_field_reservation_checked_out co 
    ON co.entity_id = dt.entity_id 
  JOIN studyroom_reservation res 
    ON res.reservation_id = co.entity_id 
 WHERE co.field_reservation_checked_out_value = 0 
   AND DATE (dt.field_reservation_datetime_value) <= NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE
```

Right now it is 9:52am, this shouldn't be showing up for the next 2 hours and 38 minutes. What I get is this:

[image]

Any idea what I may doing wrong?

edit: table alias added and screenshot

Comment: See about table aliases

Comment: Added aliases. Output still the same. I added the aliases (see edited post above). Did you mean that or something else?

Comment: Oh I know, but at least it's readable now.

Comment: Date is a DATE and NOW() is a datetime. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Tried DATE('Y-m-d H:i:s') too. Same result.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with following code

```
SELECT dt.*, co.*, res.*
FROM field_data_field_reservation_datetime AS dt 
JOIN field_data_field_reservation_checked_out AS co 
ON co.entity_id = dt.entity_id
JOIN studyroom_reservation as res 
ON res.reservation_id = co.entity_id 
WHERE co.field_reservation_checked_out_value = 0 
AND ((dt.field_reservation_datetime_value) 
<= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))
```